# Embed column containing JSON in FOR JSON AUTO

Tags: sql-server, json

If I have a table with a column containing an arbitrary valid JSON document, can I embed that document into a query returing JSON other than as a string?

For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE #Example (Name nvarchar(50) not null, Document nvarchar(max) not null);

INSERT INTO #Example VALUES 
    ('Document 1', '{ "a": "a" }'),
    ('Document 2', '{ "b": "b" }');

SELECT *
FROM #Example
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

Actual output:

```js
[
    {
        "Name":"Document 1",
        "Document":"{ \"a\": \"a\" }"
    },
    {
        "Name":"Document 2",
        "Document":"{ \"b\": \"b\" }"
    }
]
```

Desired output (note that the parsed value of `Document` has been embedded):

```js
[
    {
        "Name":"Document 1",
        "Document": { "a": "a" }
    },
    {
        "Name":"Document 2",
        "Document": { "b": "b" }
    }
]
```

Comment: Note: I don't think https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/115670/16496 is a duplicate since it is troubleshooting the fact that `JSON_VALUE` doesn't exist in previous versions - though it does refer to this issue.  The referenced `JSON_VALUE(D.DATA,'$')` does not work, and I can't find any blog referring to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `JSON_QUERY` with no path to prevent escaping

```
drop table if exists #Example
CREATE TABLE #Example (Name nvarchar(50) not null, Document nvarchar(max) not null);

INSERT INTO #Example VALUES 
    ('Document 1', '{ "a": "a" }'),
    ('Document 2', '{ "b": "b" }');

SELECT name, JSON_QUERY(Document) Document
FROM #Example
FOR JSON AUTO;
```

outputs

```
[
  {
    "name":"Document 1",
    "Document":{ "a": "a" }
  },
  {
    "name":"Document 2",
    "Document":{ "b": "b" }
  }
]
```